# Apache 2.4: Block access to xmlrpc.php of all domains

Tags: apache-2.4, xmlrpc

I would like to block the access to xmlrpc.php

I created a file in

`/etc/apache2/conf.d/block.conf`

and added the following content:

```
<FilesMatch "(^\.|wp-config\.php|xmlrpc\.php|(?<!robots)\.txt|(liesmich|readme)\.*)"> 
Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

If I try any domain on the server I'm still getting access: example.com/xmlrpc.php

I would have expected an "Forbidden"-error.

Comment: Please, can you try removing the "require" line, and using, instead " Order allow,deny" followed by "Deny from all"? (sorry for poor formatting: I'm on mobile)

Comment: It is Apache 2.4, so it is the new statement, the statement you are describing is for Apache 2.2

Comment: What is th result if you try to add it directly in apache conf file ? (and then restart server to reload configuration)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your syntax is correct but it seems directory /etc/apache2/conf.d not included in /etc/apache2/apache.conf. So either you can include this file with below syntax or move block.conf in directory **/etc/apache2/conf-enabled** which included in apache(ubuntu) by default.

open file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf in vim or your favroite editor and add below line at the end

```
Include /etc/apache2/conf.d/block.conf
```

Restart apache and check, it should be work

Comment: Thanks for your reply:

It should be included: `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`-> `Include conf.d/`

Comment: If your issue solved with this solution can you please mark this question correct

Comment: It is not solved yet ;) I meant that the configuration file should already be included, as `Include conf.d/` is already present in apache2.conf.

Comment: You should have `IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf` not `Include conf.d/` so it is normal that it is not read. Vaibhav is right, his solution works.

Comment: FWIW, the Apache `conf.d/` remains for legacy reasons. On more recent Debian and Ubuntu systems, the preferred way would be to put your custom conf file in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/`. Then enable it with `a2enconf block`.